# Swift - How creating first time app launch local notification?

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I have added these in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
self.createLocalNotification()
```

And then, calling below function.

```
func createLocalNotification() {

    let localNotification = UILocalNotification()

    localNotification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 3)
    // localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1
    localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

    localNotification.userInfo = [
        "id": "not_id0",
        "message": "Check notification"
    ]

    localNotification.alertBody = "Check notification"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)

}
```

To cancel this notification, I have tried below in **didReceiveLocalNotification** But still display notification every App launching.

```
       let app:UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        for oneEvent in app.scheduledLocalNotifications! {
            let notification = oneEvent as UILocalNotification
            let userInfoCurrent = notification.userInfo! as! [String:AnyObject]
            let id = userInfoCurrent["id"]! as! String
            if id == "not_id0" {
                //Cancelling local notification
                app.cancelLocalNotification(notification)
                break;
            }
        }
```

How Can I create first time local notification? If someone explain It would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `NSUserDefaults` as such:

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` in your `AppDelegate`:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    ...

    if let haveShownFirstRunNotification = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("haveShownFirstRunNotification") {
        if !haveShownFirstRunNotification {
            createLocalNotification()
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And in `createLocalNotification`:

```
func createLocalNotification() {

    ...

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "haveShownFirstRunNotification")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add flag in in userDefaults and then check if

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("notified")
```

if not, open notification method and there place

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "notified")
```